# I can connect to database only one time

Tags: java, postgresql

I started learning databases in java with postgres. I created database and now need to add  there some data. I can add data succesfully only one time, then i get SQLException and can't add anything to database, so i need to launch my project again. Where did i go wrong? 
Here is method for adding: (if its not enough, i can add what is needed)

```
  public final Connection CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection
            (url, login, pass);
    public void sqlAddData(Algorithm codec, String input, String translated) throws SQLException {

        try (CONNECTION) {
            java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
            String add = " insert into db.public.history ( codec, input, translated, date)  values(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement prepared = CONNECTION.prepareStatement(add);
            prepared.setString(1, String.valueOf(codec));
            prepared.setString(2, input);
            prepared.setString(3, translated);
            prepared.setTimestamp(4, date);
            prepared.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.warning("Error with database");
        }
        CONNECTION.close();
    }
```

Thanks for help and i'm sorry, if it is noob question, i'm just learning.

Comment: You should learn the basics first before you try to learn databases. For example, when you get an exception, you print the stacktrace instead of displaying "Error with database". Otherwise you'll never know **what** the error was with the database.

Comment: to add to @Kayaman you need to see specifically what `e` error is not just your own *Error with database* that's not really helpful for you.

Comment: changed exception to stacktrace and i get this -org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:714)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:274)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:198)

Comment: it's quite explicit. The connection is closed after the fisrt call and you still try to use it

Comment: thank you, can you tell me how i should fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you instantiate your connection **before** your method with :

`public final Connection CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, pass);`

Which means, if you close it **inside** your method you will **not** be able to reuse this connection **unless** you create a new one (instantiate a new one).

To fix your problem here is what you can do :

```java
public final Connection CONNECTION;

public void sqlAddData(Algorithm codec, String input, String translated) throws SQLException {

    CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, pass);

    try (CONNECTION) {

        java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        String add = " insert into db.public.history ( codec, input, translated, date)  values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement prepared = CONNECTION.prepareStatement(add);
        prepared.setString(1, String.valueOf(codec));
        prepared.setString(2, input);
        prepared.setString(3, translated);
        prepared.setTimestamp(4, date);
        prepared.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        // Handle your exception correctly or throw it.

    }
}
```

**Note** you can also use [`try-catch-finally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) to **safely close** your connection. I didn't show you how to [catch](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-java/) your exception I will let you do some digging yourself ;)

**Also note** that you are using [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which remove the finally block and still close your connection safely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As i understand , your answer should work for me, but it's not and this is strange.  As a temporary solution i will use this method with connection what instantiated inside of method, not outside. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Its because you close the connection after one call.

CONNECTION.close(); is the last thing you do and that closes the connection, if u wanna add data again you need to open the connection once again, or wait to close when you dont wanna add anything more.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can only connect to the database one time is because you're closing the open connection by wrapping the Connection object in a try-with-resources statement. Also, you're calling close on Connection after that statement which is redundant.

A solution to this problem would be to use connection pooling. Some good options are [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) and [C3P0](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/).